# Is it possible to have conditional mocking of methods that take no arguments?

Tags: java, mockito

mockito masters, I have a challenge for you! ;)

I have a method that takes no arguments and I would like to mock its behaviour as to provide different results, depending on external conditions.

For instance, I'd like to do something like this:

```
MyInterface myMock = mock(MyInterface.class);
Sky sky = buildRandomSkyColor();

when(myMock.methodWithNoArguments()).thenReturn("blue").if(sky.isBlue());
when(myMock.methodWithNoArguments()).thenReturn("grey").if(sky.isGrey());
```

Is it possible to have this conditional kind of behaviour on Mockito? I've also tried using `doStub()` and `doAnswer()`, but got nowhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can make the method return a value which is dependent on class members for example (field, other methods)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a custom answer to do this

```
MyInterface myMock = mock(MyInterface.class);
Sky sky = buildRandomSkyColor();

when(myMock.methodWithNoArguments()).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>(){
    String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        if(sky.isBlue())
            return "blue";
        else
            return "gray";
    }
}
```